# Show a document library's single column as multiple columns

Tags: 2013, document-library, column, style

I have a growing SP2013 document library. In home page, I'm showing only the Name column. Now this results in just one long column on the left side of web part and an empty expanse on the right.

Is there a way I can show this single column in multiple columns? Like a List view in windows explorer?

I'm open for custom solutions too. Preferably client side (html,js) since I operate in a server restricted environment.

This is kinda what I'm looking for:

```
My Doc Library

Name Name Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CSR that will do the job:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
}

function RenderField(ctx, columnName) {
    var field = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema;
    var item = ctx.CurrentItem;
    var list = ctx.ListSchema;
    ComputedFieldRenderer(columnName);
    return ComputedFieldRenderField(ctx, field, item, list);
}

function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Header: function(ctx) {
                return "<div style='white-space: nowrap'>";
            },
            Fields: {
                "LinkFilenameNoMenu": {
                    View: function(ctx) {
                        var rows = 10;
                        var str = "";
                        if ((ctx.CurrentItemIdx) % rows == 0){ 
                            str += "<div style='padding-right: 20px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top'><span class='ms-vh2' style='padding-left: 0'>Name</span>";
                        };
                        str += "<div>" + RenderField(ctx, "LinkFilenameNoMenu") + "</div>";
                        if ((ctx.CurrentItemIdx + 1) % rows == 0){ 
                            str += "</div>";
                        };
                        return str;
                    },
                }
            },
            Footer: function(ctx) {
                return "</div>";
            }
        },
        ListTemplateType: 101
    });
}
RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/MultiColumn.js"), init);
init();
```

});

Assumptions:

1. Only the column *Name (linked to document)* is visible
2. *Allow individual item checkboxes* is unchecked

With *var rows = ...;* you can change the number of items in each column.

And that's how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be you can add two Document Library web parts to the page and split the content based on some criteria such as : Web part 1 to show items with ID 1 -100 and Web part 2 to show items with ID 100 onwards etc..

Comment: Thats a nice idea.  I'll maybe set 2 filter conditions in each view and add it in.

Answer (score 0):

There is out of the box method to show single column to max two columns by changing the `default` style to `Document details` style

- Open Libray > from the above ribbon > click on modify the view > beside style select `Document details`.

[image]

- You can also use items limit to use `paging` and allow show short list.

[image]

The `Document details` should be shown as the following

[image]